# Displaying a HTML email with apple-inline img tag?

Tags: 14.04, email, apple, html

When I receive a HTML email from a Mac user that includes an inline image like the following, the image does not display when I render the HTML (in Chrome, Firefox, etc.).

```
<img apple-inline="yes" id="21142EAC-5EE0-4297-B3D5-E97AB1FF39DC"
     height="167" width="188" apple-width="yes" apple-height="yes"
     src="cid:1408E1B5-019F-41BD-BD66-C1A8451AAC49@nc.rr.com">
```

How do I make it render? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this is a known problem.

The only solutions I have found are for the Mac users... If this is a one-time thing, you can ask the sender to install [this plugin](http://lokiware.info/Attachment-Tamer), that should fix it as [stated here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3209246?start=0&tstart=0).